# Eclipse XSD editor

Tags: eclipse, xsd, eclipse-indigo

How do you launch or install the Eclipse XSD editor?

According to [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Introduction_to_the_XSD_Editor) it seems it should work out-of-the-box. I created the `XMLExamples` project and when I open `Catalogue.xsd` Eclipse treats it as a text file. If I choose `Open With > Other...` there's no XSD editor on the list.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo (3.7) on Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a broken installation somehow (unless you just misread what the XML Schema editor is).

Comment: Not a broken installation. Turns out the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers package doesn't include the XSD editor.

Comment: How'd you get the example project, then?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Apparently the XSD editor wasn't included in my package (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers). I added it using:

> Help > Install New Software...

Work with (enter your Eclipse version, here Photon):

> Photon - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon

Filter by "XML" - as "XSD" wouldn't return the XSD editor (eventually untick "Hide items that are already installed" in case it's already installed):

> Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development

And then:

> Eclipse XML Editors and Tools

Example with Photon:

[image]

Comment: The Java EE stuff is included in the "Java EE" download of Eclipse.

Comment: Even Eclipse Luna for Java Developer doesn't come up with XSD Editor, I went to Install New Software -> Selected http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna and then from the displayed list I selected XML Editor (It is inside Web,XML,Java EE and OSGI)

Comment: This *almost* still works. I added it today by selecting `all available sites` and then using the filter to search for `xsd`. I was then able to install an *XSD Manager*

Comment: This works great. I'm wondering if there is a way to search Eclipse when you have an XSD open. It doesn't seem to search.

Answer (score 7):

Which [Eclipse package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) did you install? The XSD editor isn't included with all of them. If you click on "details" for any package, you can see the included features. The one you're looking for is **org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature**.

Comment: +1 This pointed me in the right direction. I had installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. However, the package is org.eclipse.wst.xsl.feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can go alternatively to `eclipse market place` `(Help>Eclipse Market place)` and search for `XSD Editor`, you will see the one provided by `The eclipse foundation` which will be like the following. I already have it installed, so it is asking me to update/uninstall. If you have it as well, then it will show you the same screenshot.

[image]