# Free version of Visual XML/XSD Editor

Tags: xml, xsd

Anybody can recommend a free version of Visual Xml/Xsd editor?

I don't expect to be as good as Altova Xml Spy, but ideally it can provide similar or something close.

Comment: Eclipse has an XML editor. What IDE do you code in? VS must have as well.

Comment: I use VS2010, but it is not so good to support large/complex schema.

Comment: See [XML Schema editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_editors) and [Comparison of XML editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XML_editors) on Wikipedia

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[xmlfox](http://www.xmlfox.com/) is a good free editor that supports XSD. I however like Oxygen XML Editor. It is very cheap for the functionality it provides.

[EditiX](http://free.editix.com/) supports visual editing, however it is only free for 30 days. See the below picture.

[image]

Comment: I tried it before, it does not seem to support XSD tree style editing very well, like http://www.altova.com/images/shots/xml_schema_editor.gif

Comment: great, EditiX looks like the one I am looking for.

Comment: Just a note, if using EditiX Lite (free), that release is based on their 2008 version. For some users, that may not be an issue, but for Intel Mac users, the Lite edition won't work, as it's for PowerPC. Try their 2012 release for an updated Mac release: http://www.editix.com/download.html (30 day trial)

Comment: It seems xmlfox require registration to assign XSD. The interface doesn't seem compatible with windows 10. but nice gallery of traffic lights pictures

Answer (score 4):

The eclipse xml/xsd editing tools are fairly decent, see the installation options on this question :
[Eclipse XSD editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386336/eclipse-xsd-editor)